# Webdriver stops working on upgrading Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium, firefox-addon, webdriver

On upgrading Firefox from 3.6 to 12 . I am not able to make webdriver work.A script previously created in FF3.6 is not working on FF12.Are there any changes needed to be done after the upgrade . Following exception is thrown on running the script.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe) on port 7055;

Build info: version: '2.12.0', revision: '14666', time: '2011-11-10 18:36:18'
System info: os.name: 'Windows Vista', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:149)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:79)
    at script.Individual.TestGetQuotesPage(Individual.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodHelper.invokeMethod(MethodHelper.java:644)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:546)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:700)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1002)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:137)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:121)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:909)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:618)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:499)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:332)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:327)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:299)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:204)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createAndRunSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:915)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:879)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:787)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:73)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:124)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous4326webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found

    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start
```

What can be the possible reasons for this?

Comment: upgrade to 2.21. It will work.

Comment: Ya!! works fine on using 2.21 version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to upgrade your version of Selenium to get this work. Firefox 12 is only available with from around 2.17-ish.

Currently 2.21 is the latest version